# Python Selenium: How to get text from span class

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to get text from span class using selenium webdriver below is the code which I have tried but no result

Output should: Marketplace listings – 72

Code trials:

```html
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//h2[@class='jxuftiz4 jwegzro5 hl4rid49 icdlwmnq gvxzyvdx aeinzg81']//span").get_attribute("innerText")
```

Here is the html

```html
<div class="bdao358l om3e55n1 g4tp4svg alzwoclg cqf1kptm jez8cy9q gvxzyvdx i0rxk2l3 laatuukc gjezrb0y abh4ulrg">
    <div class="om3e55n1 g4tp4svg bdao358l alzwoclg cqf1kptm jez8cy9q gvxzyvdx">
        <div class="bdao358l om3e55n1 g4tp4svg alzwoclg cqf1kptm cgu29s5g dnr7xe2t">
            <div class="bdao358l om3e55n1 g4tp4svg alzwoclg cqf1kptm jez8cy9q gvxzyvdx r227ecj6 gt60zsk1">
                <div class="bdao358l om3e55n1 g4tp4svg tccefgj0 ebnioo9u m733yx0p"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="bdao358l om3e55n1 g4tp4svg alzwoclg cqf1kptm jez8cy9q gvxzyvdx r227ecj6 gt60zsk1">
                <div class="om3e55n1 g4tp4svg bdao358l alzwoclg cqf1kptm jez8cy9q gvxzyvdx o9wcebwi h6ft4zvz">
                    <div class="bdao358l om3e55n1 g4tp4svg alzwoclg cqf1kptm cgu29s5g dnr7xe2t">
                        <div class="bdao358l om3e55n1 g4tp4svg alzwoclg cqf1kptm jez8cy9q gvxzyvdx">
                            <div class="alzwoclg cqf1kptm siwo0mpr gu5uzgus">
                                <div class="jroqu855 nthtkgg5">
                                    <h2 class="jxuftiz4 jwegzro5 hl4rid49 icdlwmnq gvxzyvdx aeinzg81" dir="auto">
                                        <span class="gvxzyvdx aeinzg81 t7p7dqev gh25dzvf exr7barw b6ax4al1 gem102v4 ncib64c9 mrvwc6qr sx8pxkcf f597kf1v cpcgwwas m2nijcs8 hxfwr5lz hpj0pwwo sggt6rq5 innypi6y pbevjfx6 ztn2w49o" dir="auto">
                                            <span class="b6ax4al1 lq84ybu9 hf30pyar om3e55n1 tr46kb4q" style="-webkit-box-orient: vertical; -webkit-line-clamp: 2; display: -webkit-box;">Marketplace listings – 72</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure of the answer yet but I am pretty sure you probably want to change the element search to something else if you can't find it by xpath. Maybe try by css selector or by partial name. There are a couple different ways to find elements. When I struggle finding elements I usually use this document. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the effective portion from the given HTML:

```
<h2 class="jxuftiz4 jwegzro5 hl4rid49 icdlwmnq gvxzyvdx aeinzg81" dir="auto">
    <span class="gvxzyvdx aeinzg81 t7p7dqev gh25dzvf exr7barw b6ax4al1 gem102v4 ncib64c9 mrvwc6qr sx8pxkcf f597kf1v cpcgwwas m2nijcs8 hxfwr5lz hpj0pwwo sggt6rq5 innypi6y pbevjfx6 ztn2w49o" dir="auto">
        <span class="b6ax4al1 lq84ybu9 hf30pyar om3e55n1 tr46kb4q" style="-webkit-box-orient: vertical; -webkit-line-clamp: 2; display: -webkit-box;">Marketplace listings – 72</span>
    </span>
</h2>
```

To extract the text ***Marketplace listings – 72*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2[dir="auto"] span[dir="auto"] > span[style*='webkit-box-orient']"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[@dir="auto"]/span[@dir="auto"]/span[contains(@style, 'webkit-box-orient') and text()]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this xpath expression instead:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[@dir='auto']/span").get_attribute("innerText")
```

I tested the expression with your HTML example and confirmed it works.

OUTPUT

```
'Marketplace listings – 72'
```